# MySQL plugin Standard is not loaded

Tags: mysql

I was trying to reinstall MySQL server 8.0 in order to use legacy authentication method, but got the following error in log when installer was attempting to start the server:

> MySQL error 0: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root'
>   using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Plugin
>   'Standard' is not loaded

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`caching_sha2_password` is the default authentication mechanism in 8.0. So use a client that support this. Or using the mysql-8.0 client, create a new user using [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#create-user-authentication):

```
CREATE USER 'vyacheslav'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: Actually even when i changed authentication method, it was showing me same message - "Plugin 'Standard' is not loaded" and still could not start the server.

Comment: maybe that's why I didn't say to change it.